# How to make systemd service start at boot

Tags: systemd, reboot, nix

I installed the Nix package manager on XUbuntu 20.04. It added a `nix-daemon` service. I would like to start the `nix-daemon` service on boot. If I type the following commands the service runs and works fine until I halt the machine, but after a reboot the service is not running, and I need to run these commands again.

It seems that systemd disables the service or forgets that it was enabled. How can I tell systemd to enable the service and leave it enabled?

```shellsession
$ sudo systemctl status nix-daemon
Unit nix-daemon.service could not be found.
```

```shellsession
$ sudo systemctl enable nix-daemon
```

```shellsession
$ sudo systemctl status nix-daemon
● nix-daemon.service - Nix Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/4vz8sh9ngx34ivi0bw5hlycxdhvy5hvz-nix-2.3.7/lib/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● nix-daemon.socket
```

```shellsession
$ sudo service nix-daemon start
● nix-daemon.service - Nix Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/4vz8sh9ngx34ivi0bw5hlycxdhvy5hvz-nix-2.3.7/lib/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-04-16 04:35:15 BST; 2s ago
TriggeredBy: ● nix-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 55329 (nix-daemon)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9091)
     Memory: 13.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nix-daemon.service
             └─55329 nix-daemon --daemon

Apr 16 04:35:15 wayfire systemd[1]: Started Nix Daemon.
Apr 16 04:35:15 wayfire nix-daemon[55329]: warning: unknown setting 'experimental-features'
Apr 16 04:35:15 wayfire nix-daemon[55329]: warning: unknown setting 'keep-derivarions'
```

**EDIT:**

Contents of the `/etc/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service` that was created by the installer (I didn't modify it):

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Nix Daemon
RequiresMountsFor=/nix/store
RequiresMountsFor=/nix/var
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/nix/var/nix/daemon-socket

[Service]
ExecStart=@/nix/store/4vz8sh9ngx34ivi0bw5hlycxdhvy5hvz-nix-2.3.7/bin/nix-daemon nix-daemon --daemon
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There is no /etc/default/nix file.

```
$ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

Comment: RIght after you type: "sudo systemctl enable nix-daemon" you then need to type "
"sudo systemctl start nix-daemon" - using "service nix-daemon start" calls "systemctl start nix-daemon".  Post your nix-daemon.service file and the /etc/default/nix if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of reasons why a service would not load at boot despite running `systemctl enable thename.service`. In my case, `/etc/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service` had been created by the installer (I guess?), and was a symlink to `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service`. My `/nix` is a separate partition, and systemd was trying to read the `.service` file before mounting the partition (and therefore failed to recognize the service). `journalctl | grep nix-daemon` allowed me to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you one way to do it. First type:

```
systemctl get-default
```

You will probably get `graphical.target`. Then add the following lines to your service file

```
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

to tell systemd, which target starts your service. If your default target is different, use it instead of `graphical.target` (e.g. `multi-user.target`,...). Then reload systemd with

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

to make sure the changes in your service file are reloaded. After that the service should start with the reboot.

Comment: Thanks! Is adding `WantedBy=the-correct.target` something that **replaces** `sudo systemctl enable some-service`, or is it something that should be done **before or after** `sudo systemctl enable some-service`?

Comment: You need to add `[Install] WantedBy=...`, *then* use `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable ...`